# php functions and ($user = null) {

Tags: php

If I write a function like

```
function exd ($user = null) {
     return $user; 
}
```

If I call the function with no variable like

```
exd();
```

The value will be `null`?

```
But if I give the function a variable does the variable that I give become `$user`?

exd('account1');
```

Thanks couldn't find it in the docs so thought I would ask here?!

Comment: [You didn't look very hard.](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Comment: *"couldn't find it in the docs"* - It's not exactly hidden. http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `exd()` returns null because `$user` is set to null as default value.If you use `exd('account1')` it'll return  `account1`. Because `$user` variable **inside** the function gets a value `account1`. Outside of the function you wont be able to get the value of `$user`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample to work from that be helpful.

```
<?PHP
function exd($user = NULL){
    return $user;
}
//Does nothing outside the function
exd();

//Does nothing outside the function
exd("Joe");

//$foo now = NULL
$foo = exd();

//$foo now = string Joe
$foo = exd("Joe");

?>
```

Here is a secondary function that may be useful if you did want to modify $user

```
<?PHP
$user = "Jill";
function exd(&$user, $newName=NULL){
    $user = $newName;
}

//Outputs Jill
echo $user;
//Outputs Joe
exd($user, "Joe");
echo $user
//Outputs null
exd($user);
echo $user;

?>
```

This would be more useful if user were something more complicated than a string.